# "Autocomplete = off" does not work with input in Cakephp

Tags: html, cakephp-2.0

I have one question. My input field always auto input. 
I find some solutions, but does not work.

I try all of these, but not working for me. Have you any ideas?

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('autocorrect' => 'off',  'autocapitalize' => 'off', 'autocomplete' => 'off'));
```

or

```
 echo $this->Form->input('username','autocomplete' => 'off'));
```

Comment: it works for me. what browser you're using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. Now I test in Fire fox. It works. Why Chrome not working?

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is

```
echo $this->Form->input('ModelName.fieldname',array('autocomplete'=>'off'));
```

Does the HTML input is generated correctly? Can you check?